# How to rewrite URL.php in htaccess problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite every file in my .htaccess from `.php` to a clean URL without it, but I can't make it work.

My current code is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(blog)\.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.phP
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url.info [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.info/$1 [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /url1.php /url2.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 months"
</IfModule>

# Deflate Compression by FileType
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
</IfModule>

# Deflate Compression by MimeType</span>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch ".(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|txt|html)$">
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

When I want to access URL1 it gives a 404. It works by itself and with everything else but not when I add the php part at the beginning.
I hope you can help me, thank you .

Comment: Probably better to tag your with `apache` since `.htaccess` is a feature of Apache  web server, not PHP.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.phP` - the uppercase `P` will cause this condition to always fail.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

The first Rewrite condition and rule combo redirects everything everything that ends with ".php" to the same address without it (it's stripping the .php from the URL). The second condition and rule combo remaps the requested resource back to load the php file (but the address will remain stripped).

Comment: It didn't... I wrote the complete htaccess code, I hope you can see a mistake because I can't figure it out... Thank you for your help

Comment: It works for me... I did test it using XAMPP in Windows. Also tested on a FreeBSD hosting server - works too.

Comment: Few things to consider from your whole code:

1. The redirect to HTTPS should be at the very beginning. 2. No need to start rewriteengine multiple times. 3. The redirect to www should be the second after HTTPS. You can eventually combine them in one rule.

Comment: @Damysus When you say "it didn't" - did it do _anything_? Did you replace the corresponding directives in your current `.htaccess` file? The `.htaccess` you've added to your question is incorrect. And what are the URLs you are requesting/testing?

Comment: Hi, yes. I did write the code sent on here. It works until I try to redirect 301 from url1 to url2. I tried deleting the whole code and adding bit by bit and it fails with the php par (404 when you go to URL without .php and 200OK with .the .php extension.